# Find parent array from object

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsarray

I have an array of model objects
The model object **Item** having 2 properties

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong)NSString *attribute;
 @property (nonatomic, strong)NSMutableArray *subItems;
```

In the subItems, I can have a same Item Objects, If I again access second level array, I will get the Item object, Inside this **Item** object again array of Items it will be there.  So It can traverse through n numbers.

How can I traverse front and back this hierarchy if I have current **Item** object.

Comment: You need a reverse relationship.

Comment: you have these in nsobject?

Comment: yes it is in nsobject